# Existing silverlight app to WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How to customize the existing silverlight appliction, to be able to run on windows phone 7?
What are all the issues or API's or resolution problems will occur during the Migration?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to start.

[Class Library Support for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470087%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

[Differences Between Silverlight on Windows and Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426930%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

[Features Supported in Silverlight for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426931%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Also, migrating your code across to the Windows Phone Application project template can be a less bumpy road unless you want to get into the detail of how the startup projects vary.

Note also, Silverlight for WP7 is based on SL3 with some additions/exclusions to suit the mobile platform.

Answer (score 1):

You don't "customize" an existing silverlight application, you re-design.  Something designed to run on a decent size screen with keyboard and mouse input devices will not be well suited for a touch screen device with limited screen space.

As to "all" the API issues, there are too many you need to carefully check the documentation.  As a general rule if its not in Silverlight 3 only in Silverlight 4 then it probably isn't in WP7, however there are exceptions.

Comment: oh.. Then do i have to develop a same app twice? one for desktop & one for WP7? No other way Antony??

Comment: I heard that WP7 will support silverlight app extensively? Will it  ease this migration?

Comment: @mhn:  No you don't have to develop the same app twice.  If you are careful you can create source code which will run on a phone and in a silverlight plugin.   How many users you would be pleasing with such a one-size fits all app would be questionable.