# Develop a Windows mobile app from existing silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, microsoft-metro

I have developed a Dynamic Data Grid Silver light 4.0 Web application. [you can assume it as a Data Pulling Grid with some animations]
This web application is very huge with some 10 Xaml files and a big Ms-Sql Database. 
I also used web services from Sivlerlight to get data.

Now, I am planning to build a WINDOWS Mobile app for my software. 
I need some suggestions for this.

Do i need to start the development from scratch for Windows app.
(or)
Can i reuse the Silver light Xaml files that i used in the Web application. 
If i use the same XAP file, will it cost any performance issue ?

Any Concerns/ Improvisations / Comments ?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517825/existing-silverlight-app-to-wp7

Comment: I disagree on the duplicate, he said "Windows Mobile", not "Windows Phone" - the two platforms differ.

Comment: @David - He tagged it as windows-phone-7, his description is consistent with having some knowledge that WP7 is built on Silverlight, I think it was a very reasonable assumption that he meant WP7 and not "Windows Mobile".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's Windows Mobile (and not Windows Phone) then no. Microsoft never made Silverlight available to Windows Mobile (there were plans to port it to WM6.1 originally, but they were ditched when WP7 work started).

If it's Windows Phone, then it depends. I understand that Silverlight on WP7 has a different widget-set available, but your XAML and application code should work with only minor modifications (of course, assuming you have redesigned to fit WP7's screen form-factor).